# Java Swing: slightly modify existing keyboard behaviour? (right arrow should initially set cursor to position 0)

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events

If a Java Swing JTextField gets the focus, all its text is marked.

Now, I would like to modify the behaviour, so that if the user now presses the right arrow, the cursor should be set to the texts beginning (position 0).

I'm able to get the RIGHT Key event and set the cursor to position 0, 
but I don't know how to pass the RIGHT Key event to the original code so that it can handle the normal behaviour.

```
JTextField preisFieldEUR = new JTextField(…);

AbstractAction right = new AbstractAction() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (preisFieldEUR.getSelectionEnd() - preisFieldEUR.getSelectionStart() == preisFieldEUR.getText().length()) {
      preisFieldEUR.setSelectionStart(0);
      preisFieldEUR.setSelectionEnd(0);
    } else {
      // Todo: How to pass this event to the original keyboard handler to
      // keep the normal behaviour?
    }
  }
};

preisFieldEUR.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), right);
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Action oldAction = preisFieldEUR.getActionMap().get("caret-forward"); // probably another parameter?
AbstractAction right = new AbstractAction() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (preisFieldEUR.getSelectionEnd() - preisFieldEUR.getSelectionStart() == preisFieldEUR.getText().length()) {
      preisFieldEUR.setSelectionStart(0);
      preisFieldEUR.setSelectionEnd(0);
    } else {
        oldAction.actionPeformed(e)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Soooo great!, thank you **very** much! `caret-forward` is perfect, I keep your comment just in case other users tries to transfer it to another situation.